# "Error: File /etc/sensors3.conf: Permission denied" when running htop

Tags: 18.04, htop

When running `htop` I get

> Error: File `/etc/sensors3.conf`: Permission denied

the permissions:

```
$ ls -l /etc/sensors3.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10368 Apr  5  2017 /etc/sensors3.conf
```

`htop` still works as expected, but what's up with this error?

I've also tried:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lm-sensors
```

which made no difference.

```
which htop
/usr/bin/htop
```

Comment: `which htop` please. Maybe it is a snap?

Comment: it looks like not. I recall that I did install with apt.

Comment: Maybe run `sudo htop`, i think it's unsafe when you run as superuser but give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Snap maintainer here. That's just a warning message caused by missing permissions due to snap confinement. As a result, *optional* CPU temperature stats are unavailable (`N/A` is shown to the right of each CPU bar, if enabled).

Just updated the snap with support for manually connecting the `hardware-observe` interface, which fixes it (and also adds support for battery stats, btw). So, you just need to:

```
$ sudo snap connect htop:hardware-observe
```

Also, before just uninstalling the snap, note that depending on your OS release the snap might be much newer than the one in the OS repositories (eg. 3.0.4 vs 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even after install with apt and fixed it by removing the snap version of `htop`.

```
sudo snap remove htop
```

Comment: I've logged this with the snap maintainer https://github.com/maxiberta/htop-snap/issues/10